# openssl_decrypt not decrypting data stored with openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

I need a simple encrypt/decrypt for nonsensitive data that I cannot store as plain text. I put together this class and openssl_decrypt is returning false but I can't figure out why.

```
$ssl=new ssl();

$x="this was encrpyted";
echo "<br />1".$x;
$json=$ssl->encrypt($x);
echo "<br />2".$json;
echo "<br />3".$ssl->decrypt($json);

class ssl {

    private $cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
    private $options=0;

    public function encrypt($plaintext) {
        $key=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $ivlen=openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher);
        $iv=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext=openssl_encrypt(
            $plaintext, 
            $this->cipher, 
            $key,
            $this->options,
            $iv,
            $tag
        );
        $a=[];
        $a["key"]=bin2hex($key);    
        $a["iv"]=bin2hex($iv);  
        $a["ciphertext"]=$ciphertext;   
        return json_encode($a);
    }

    public function decrypt($json) {
        $a=json_decode($json,true);
        return openssl_decrypt(
            $a["ciphertext"], 
            $this->cipher, 
            hex2bin($a["key"]),
            $this->options,
            hex2bin($a["iv"])
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or output?

Comment: You are almost certainly better off using more modern [built-in functions](https://www.php.net/sodium) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't storing the tag value that's returned from the encryption process. As [mentioned in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#refsect1-function.openssl-encrypt-parameters), this is required for GCM and CCM ciphers.

Also cleaned up your code a bit:

```
<?php
class Ssl {

    private static $cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
    private static $options=0;

    public static function encrypt(string $plaintext): ?string
    {
        $key        = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $ivlen      = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::$cipher);
        $iv         = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
            $plaintext,
            self::$cipher,
            $key,
            self::$options,
            $iv,
            $tag
        );
        $a = [
            "key"        => bin2hex($key),
            "iv"         => bin2hex($iv),
            "tag"        => bin2hex($tag),
            "ciphertext" => $ciphertext,
        ];
        return json_encode($a);
    }

    public static function decrypt(string $json): ?string
    {
        $a = json_decode($json);
        $result = openssl_decrypt(
            $a->ciphertext,
            self::$cipher,
            hex2bin($a->key),
            self::$options,
            hex2bin($a->iv),
            hex2bin($a->tag)
        );
        if ($result === false) {
            return null;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$x = "this was encrpyted";
echo "<br />\n1 $x";
$json = Ssl::encrypt($x);
echo "<br />\n2 $json";
echo "<br />\n3 " . Ssl::decrypt($json);
```

Output:

```
<br />
1 this was encrpyted
<br />
2 {"key":"3b48ecde64b8e2789991604678cc9fb9","iv":"307443dc8d114773fc02d0c4","tag":"8c66a2b0094435345b751b2dec5231a9","ciphertext":"EiIxe2hp0aONf41oBRuvwtjr"}
<br />
3 this was encrpyted
```

Comment: the tag storing helped me get out of this thanks